# interfaced type-bound procedures in Fortran

Tags: interface, fortran, type-bounds

I am trying to define an `interface`d procedure as a type-bound procedure in a Fortran `type` definition, but it seems it doesn't work as one would expect. Consider the following module:

```
module example_module
implicit none
private

interface add_them
  module procedure add_them_integer,add_them_real
end interface add_them

type, public :: foo
  integer, private :: a=1,b=2
  real, private :: c=4.,d=5.
contains
  procedure, public :: add => add_them
end type foo

contains
subroutine add_them_integer(self,x)
class(foo), intent(in) :: self
integer, intent(in) :: x
print *,self%a+self%b+x
end subroutine add_them_integer

subroutine add_them_real(self,x)
class(foo), intent(in) :: self
real, intent(in) :: x
print *,self%c+self%d+x
end subroutine add_them_real
end module example_module
```

and the corresponding program that uses the module:

```
program example
use example_module
implicit none
type(foo) :: foofoo
call foofoo%add(1)
call foofoo%add(2.)
end program example
```

I would expect this to compile and results should be 4 and 11. However, gfortran reports the following error:

```
procedure, public :: add => add_them
         1
Error: 'add_them' must be a module procedure or an external procedure with an explicit interface at (1)
```

A workaround is to use `generic` type-bound procedure instead of an `interface`d one, so that the module is as follows:

```
module example_module
implicit none
private

type, public :: foo
  integer, private :: a=1,b=2
  real, private :: c=4.,d=5.
contains
  generic, public :: add => add_them_integer,add_them_real
  procedure, private :: add_them_integer,add_them_real
end type foo

contains
subroutine add_them_integer(self,x)
class(foo), intent(in) :: self
integer, intent(in) :: x
print *,self%a+self%b+x
end subroutine add_them_integer

subroutine add_them_real(self,x)
class(foo), intent(in) :: self
real, intent(in) :: x
print *,self%c+self%d+x
end subroutine add_them_real
end module example_module
```

This works as expected. However, I cannot use a `generic` procedure. The above is just a simplified example to demonstrate the problem, but in my actual code 'add_them' cannot be a `generic` procedure because 'foo' is actually a derived-type and 'add_them' overrides a procedure defined in the parent type; gfortran (at least) does not allow `generic` procedures overriding base procedures. To bypass this restriction, I thought I should use an `interface` instead, but as you can see in the above example, although 'add_them' is defined correctly, compiler complains that "'add_them' must be a module procedure or an external procedure with an explicit interface".

Any help would be appreciated; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gfortran error for your first section of code is correct.  The way to do generic bindings is as per your "works as expected" section of code.

If a parent type has a specific binding with a certain name, then you cannot reuse that name in extensions, other than to override the specific binding.

If you want `add` (note the name `add_them` doesn't appear in your second case) to be a generic binding in extensions, then make it a generic binding in the parent.

Comment: Strictly speaking, what I was trying to do was to bypass the restriction "you cannot override non-generic procedures by generic ones", and tried to use an interfaced procedure for that purpose. I ended up doing as IanH said, making the parent procedure generic as well. This needed to add a `select type` construct to the parent procedure as well (which is actually what I wanted to avoid) but it works.

Comment: I still don't see, however, why an interfaced procedure cannot be a type-bound procedure, making `generic` procedures the only solution in the example above. Fortran 2003/2008 even allows overriding type names by an interfaced procedure, essentially making a "constructor". Why not using them as type bound procedures as well?

Comment: What you call "an interfaced procedure" is a generic interface.  The equivalent for a binding is a generic binding.  Procedures that implement bindings have requirements on them around passed arguments, etc.  If you were going to rope in the stand-alone generic interface syntax to specify generic bindings then those restrictions would have to work through that syntax.  That would be rather messy.

Comment: I was suspecting that `generic` type-bounds is the only way to go, and posted this to just be sure.
I can't complain, really. Afterall, it is those restrictions that make Fortran ideal for high performance computing, and force the programmer to write structured code avoiding potential pitfalls.